# Prove the ring can be embedded in a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ represent the finite field consisting of two elements. Consider the polynomial ring $A=\mathbb{F}_2[t,X]$ with two indeterminates over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with a new multiplication defined by the rule $Xt=t^2X$. Apparently $A$ forms a non-commutative ring with characteristic $2$. Show that $A$ can be embedded into a division ring $K$.

**Context**: In projective plane geometry, the axioms P5 (Desargues’ Theorem), P6 (Pappus’ Axiom), and P7 (Fano's Axiom) are crucial. Notably, the sole implication among these axioms is P6 $\Rightarrow$ P5. To illustrate this, it's necessary to provide an example of a projective plane where P5 holds, but neither P6 nor P7 does. To achieve this, we can examine the projective plane over a division ring $F$, denoted as $\mathbb{P}^2_F$. It is noteworthy that P5 holds in $\mathbb{P}^2_F$ regardless of the nature of $F$. Moreover, P6 holds if and only if $F$ is commutative, while P7 holds if and only if the characteristic of $F$ is not $2$. Thus, we only need to give an example of a non-commutative division ring of characteristic $2$. In Hartshorne's *Foundations of Projective Geometry*, he constructs $A$ and asserts

> ...Then one can show that $A$ can be embedded in a division ring $K$,
> which is necessarily non-commutative...

but does not offer a comprehensive proof for this assertion.

Comment: It perhaps deserves mention that there are other ways to construct a characteristic 2 noncommutative division ring. Indeed, it suffices to find a char 2 field with non-vanishing [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group). From algebraic number theory, it is known that examples for that are given by $\Bbb F_2(t)$ or $\Bbb F_2((t))$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In noncommutative algebra, the criteria for being able to carry out the analogue of the ring of fractions (right fractions, anyway) are called the [Ore conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition).

One common way to introduce noncommutative domains is to make [Ore extensions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_extension)   (Notice for our purposes we are talking about $\delta=0$ and $\sigma$ defining the endomorphism of $k[t]$ that you described.)

This is especially handy when the ring used is a field, because it ensures there's still a sort of division algorithm so that the left ideals are all principal.<sup>1</sup>  Really I sort of half expect Hartshorne meant the field endomorphism defined by that $\sigma$ from $k(t)\to k(t)$, and then to use the Ore extension $k(t)[X;\sigma]$.  If you do the Ore extension with a field and an endomorphism on it, for sure the result satisfies the Ore conditions on the left, allowing it to embed densely in a division ring.

Actually filling in all the details for the classical Ore theory is a good lecture or so. The details are not *hard* but they are a little tedious.  One good resource to consult would be Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* Chapter 4 "Rings of quotients".

Also [here is a mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/206190/19965) that might have enough details to satisfy you.

Finally, here are some [old online notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/artinnotes.pdf) by Michael Artin that contain some of an explanation.

---

<sup>1</sup> To be clear, this assumes the polynomials are written with coefficients on the left of powers of $X$, and the rule $X\lambda:=\sigma(\lambda)X$.  One could use the other-side analogue to do a mirror version.  It matters because when $\sigma$ is not onto, it does not have principal right ideals.

Comment: Can we make the division ring a bit more explicit in the given example?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg in the case where the Ore condition is satisfied, the noncommutative localization is as explicit and simple as the in the commutative world: you just have formal fractions. I would consider that to be pretty explicit. So as a set, it identifies with $\Bbb F_2(t,X)$, but we have a different multiplication.

Comment: The right ideals of $F[X;\sigma]$ need not be principal if $\sigma$ is not surjective.

Comment: @AllenBell Looked again and I see that's right: if the coefficients are written on the left and the rule commutes them from right to left across the $X$, it's left principal, not right principal.  I'll make a note.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide more detail for rschwieb's answer.  A (noncommutative) domain has a division ring of fractions if and only if it is an Ore domain.  Any Noetherian domain is an Ore domain. If $R$ is Noetherian and $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $R$, the Ore extension $R[X;\sigma]$ is Noetherian.  Thus if we start with any field $F$ and any automorphism $\sigma$ of $F[t]$, the algebra $F[t][X;\sigma]$ is an Ore domain and embeds in a division ring.

One example of this situation is to take $\sigma(t)=t+1$, which defines an automorphism of $F[t]$.  The ring $F[t][X;\sigma]$ can also be described as $F[t,X]$ with multiplication defined by the rule $Xt-tX=X$.  Thus this ring is the enveloping algebra of the non-Abelian two dimensional Lie algebra.  It is a noncommutative Noetherian domain and hence has a noncommutative division ring of fractions, no matter what the characteristic of $F$.

Hartshorne's example, as cited by the OP, works but requires more effort.  In this case, the endomorphism $\sigma$ defined by $\sigma(t)=t^2$ is not an automorphism, so the results mentioned above do not apply.  The ring $A=F[t][X;\sigma]$ is still a (noncommutative) domain, but it is not a right Ore domain, since $XA\cap tXA=0$.  However, it is a left Ore domain and hence does embed in a division ring.  To see this, we can first invert the nonzero elements of $F[t]$ to arrive at the ring $B=F(t)[X;\sigma]$, where the new $\sigma$ extends the old one in the obvious way.  As $F(t)$ is a field, one can show that every left ideal of $B$ is principal.  [This is Theorem 2.8 in *An Introduction to Noncommutative Noetherian Rings, second edition* by Goodearl and Warfield.]  Thus $B$ is a left Ore domain, and this implies that $A$ is a left Ore domain.

edit to add one detail: $B$ is an Ore localization of $A$, since it is obtained by inverting the set of nonzero elements of $F[t]$, and that set is an Ore set in $A$ (because it is closed under $\sigma$).  Thus the quotient division ring of $B$ is a quotient division ring of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for adding that!